# Trying to make my sixaxis ps3 controller work on my computer for minecraft

Tags: qt, ps3

Ok so I followed the steps on [here](http://ubuntnt.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-setup-sixaxis-controller-with.html) and on steps 8 and 9 I got this
`g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DDEVDIR=\"/dev/input\" -DICON24=\"/usr/local/share/pixmaps/qjoypad/icon24.png\" -DICON64=\"/usr/local/share/pixmaps/qjoypad/icon64.png\" -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o axis.o axis.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [axis.o] Error 127`
 
I have no idea what to do please help ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not relevant, but the instructions you used look completely different from the ones I used to get mine working.

I followed the instructions listed on the Ubuntu documentation site and it worked on the first try.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis

Either way, good luck!

Comment: Ok so I got it to work, thank you very much by the way but I installed the mouse control from the repository because the source was coming up as 404 and because of that my motion sensor is also acting like a mouse and I don't know how to stop that. If you can help me with that that would very appreciated :)